# Insert a deleted record in another schema

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, triggers, oracle11g, java-ee-6

I want to know if there is any mechanism to perform as following :
when I delete a record R1 from a table T1 in schema S1, I want to insert it to a corresponding table T1 in another schema S2.
My project is in JavaEE and I also want to know if there is any solution in JPA to handle that or I should handle it using an ORACLE trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Triggers to handle this operation.

for further explanations, Google it, then you will get plenty of resources out there on different types of triggers.

Comment: I dont find any Idea in google or other oracl forum.can u help me to find relation link? tanks